# How to correctly apply the same data transformation , used on the training dataset , on real data in a webservice?

Tags: machine-learning, data

Let's say I used **minmaxscaler** while creating my model.
Now, i'm loading that model via **Pickle** in a Flask app. Upon receiving a request containing a *datapoint* I would like to apply to it the same transformations that I applied to my training dataset before calling the *predict()* method. How do I transfer that set of transformations from one file to a webservice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just noticed that none of the answers contained the most important instruction. So here is how it's done since i already resolved this a long time ago.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.externals import joblib

pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('normalization', MinMaxScaler()),
                ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())
            ])
pipeline.fit(X)
```

The `pipeline.fit()` was missing from other answers which is very important. Once scikit function has learned the parameters of your training data **X** , you can dump that pipeline into a file and do the rest like this.

```
joblib.dump(pipeline, 'transform_predict.joblib')
pipeline = load('transform_predict.joblib') 
transformed_data = pipeline.transform(new_data)
```

This will apply the same transformations to a dataset (even if containing 1 sample) that was done on your training dataset.

**Update**

for newer version, I believe one has to read. I hit the memory limit and the following change helped.

```
with open(conf['le_embedder_file'], 'rb') as f:
    pipe_le = joblib.load(f)
```

and write

```
with open(conf['tecv_embedder_file'], 'wb') as f:
    joblib.dump(pipe_tecv, f, compress='zlib')
```

I had to read

Answer (score 3):

Rather than storing and loading many files, create a Scikit-learn transformation pipeline with all of your transformations, and then save that as a pickle or joblib file.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.externals import joblib

pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('normalization', MinMaxScaler()),
                ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())
            ])

joblib.dump(pipeline, 'transform_predict.joblib')
```

You can then just load one transformation pipeline and call fit_transform to transform the input data and get predictions for it:

```
 pipeline = load('transform_predict.joblib') 
 predictions = pipeline.predict(new_data)
```

Comment: Does this apply to dummy variables?

Comment: If you're using scikit-learn's OneHotEncoder then yes. Any scikit learn 'transformer' can be used with a pipeline, so anything that implements the TransformerMixin and BaseEstimator:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7b136e9/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py#L128

This also means you can create your own custom 'transformers' to add to a pipeline, by implementing these in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save minmaxscaler (along with model). In Flask app, you can :

1. Load scaler from file
2. Use this instance of scaler for scaling input values

> #While training
>
> ```
> from sklearn.externals import joblib
> scaler_filename = "saved_scaler"
> joblib.dump(scaler, scaler_filename)
> ```
>
> ## In Flask App
>
> ```
> scaler_filename = "saved_scaler"    
> scaler = joblib.load(scaler_filename)
> ```

Comment: Do i need to do this for every normalization library i use? i'll be loading many files into the memory, isn't there way to load something that contains every step of the data transformations?

Comment: You can save and load all scalers at the same time. Example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33497314/sklearn-dumping-model-using-joblib-dumps-multiple-files-which-one-is-the-corre